# Order of Express Routes (Specific vs General)

Tags: express, routes

Basic Express question. If I have two post routes -- one being more specific than the other.

Does the order of their placement matter? And if so, should I be positioning the specific route first, followed by the general one if I only want the specific one to be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer. Express does route sequentially. But what I hadn't understood was that by including next() the middleware continue on to the next one.

http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use